# Inserting a new row on Laravel using "save" method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am studying Laravel and trying to insert a new row in my table `estabelecimentos`.

Why is this working to insert a new row:

```php
$estabelecimento = Estabelecimento::create([
    'nome' => $nome
]);
```

And this is not working? Using `var_dump` on `save` method it returns `null`.

```php
$estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento();
$estabelecimento->nome = $nome;
$estabelecimento->save;
```

I already tried using `try/catch` but it doesn't throw errors, it just don't insert the row and returns `null` on save method.

My Class:

```php
namespace App;
    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
class Estabelecimento extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['nome'];
    
    public function Comentarios()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::Class);
    }
 }
```

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comentario extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'votes'];
    
    public function Estabelecimento()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo(Estabelecimento::Class);
    }
}
```

##### Table `estabelecimentos`

| name | type | extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint(20) | PK - AUTOINCREMENT |
| nome | varchar(100) | - |

Comment: You need to call method `save()` not property `save`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`save` is a method and hence you call it with `()`.

so, replace the following line of code:

```php
$estabelecimento->save;
```

with the following:

```php
$estabelecimento->save(); // focus on `()`
```

---

Remember to always look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method